# How can i write ECMAScript 6 in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

How can i write ECMAScript code in Visual Studio Code ?? I tried writing  *jsconfig.json*  but am not sure about how to run that file. I even tried changing the  *tasks.json*  but even that is not helping.

Thanks In Advance,

Amala

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update April 2016:**

As of the latest version of visual studio code (1.0 at time of writing)there should be no need for jsconfig.json to enable ES6 now.

**Previous Answer:**

1. Create a new folder in your file system
2. Open the folder in VS Code:
   [image: Open folder]
3. When the folder is opened, click on the New File icon:
   [image: New file]
4. Call the file *jsconfig.json* and paste the following config:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6"
    }
}
```

Now when you create a JS file, you'll get IntelliSense and ES6 code validation:

[image: Example code]

You can find out more about ES6 support from the [VSCode Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vscode/archive/2015/07/06/vs-code-es6.aspx)

Comment: As of the latest version of visual studio code.. ( December release) ES6 support is primary. Means no need for jsconfig.json

Answer (score 2):

Add to your user settings to not show any errors when writing es6

```
"jshint.options": {
    "esversion":6
}
```